# How to replicate installed package selection from one Fedora instance to another?

Tags: fedora, yum, dnf

I have a Fedora system (A) where I have installed some packages over the time. Now I want to install Fedora on another computer (B) and I want to install the same packages on it.

In Debian terms I want to accomplish something like this:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections > pkg_sel_host_a  # on host_a
$ dpkg --set-selections < pkg_sel_host_a  # on host_b
```

But to be honest, I really want a better method to select the same packages on the new Fedora 19 system (B): I just want to install the packages from system A that were explicitly mentioned on a  `dnf install` (or `yum install`) command line - and not those that were installed as dependencies!

Why? Because perhaps dependencies have changed - and I don't want to install outdated dependencies on the new system. Plus, when I remove packages I want to remove the (possibly) then unneeded automatically installed dependencies (i.e. orphans) as well.

I've found `dnf list installed` - but it does not display if a package was explicitly selected or just installed because of a dependency.

How do I get that information on Fedora?

What is the Fedora/dnf way to replicate package selections?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Fedora 26, the Dnf `repoquery` [subcommand supports](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/pull/797) has a new option for listing all user-installed packages:

```
$ dnf repoquery --qf '%{name}' --userinstalled \
 | grep -v -- '-debuginfo$' \
 | grep -v '^\(kernel-modules\|kernel\|kernel-core\|kernel-devel\)$' > pkgs_a.lst
```

In contrast to other methods, it also lists all debuginfo packages. The additional grep in the above example filters them out.

To install the list on host B:

```
$ < pkgs_a.lst xargs dnf -y install
```

### Dnf API

With recent Dnf versions (e.g. Fedora >= 23), the package database can be queried for user installed package names via the Dnf Python API:

```
$ python3 -c 'import dnf; b = dnf.Base(); b.fill_sack(); \
  l = sorted(set(x.name for x in b.iter_userinstalled() \
       if not x.name.endswith("-debuginfo") \
          and x.name not in \
             ["kernel-modules", "kernel", "kernel-core", "kernel-devel"] )); \
  print("\n".join(l)) ' > pkgs_a.lst

# dnf install $(cat pkgs_a.lst) # on host_b
```

By default, `dnf install` aborts if one or more packages aren't available anymore. Alternatively, dnf [can be forced](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html#strict-label) to install all remaining ones:

```
# dnf install --setopt=strict=0 $(cat pkgs_a.lst) # on host_b
```

**PS:** Put the above code and more into [`user-installed.py`](https://github.com/gsauthof/utility/blob/master/user-installed.py) that also supports other distributions.

### history userinstalled

On Fedora 23 and later, Dnf provides the

```
# dnf history userinstalled
```

command that lists all user installed packages. As of 2016-11, its [usefulness is limited](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1370062) because there is no way to control its output and it prints packages fully qualified (i.e. including version information).

### userinstalled Limitations

Note that the marking of packages as user-installed has some limitations on some Fedora versions, for Fedora 23-ish era systems (from around 2015-11) the following issues are relevant):

- packages installed [via the GUI are not included](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1277115)
- packages installed [via the command-not-found handler are not included](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1284194)
- some packages installed by default (by anaconda) [are included](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1284194)

### Repoquery

On older Fedora systems, where Dnf, the Dnf API and `dnf history userinstalled` aren't available, one can use [repoquery](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/RepoQuery) instead, e.g.:

```
$ repoquery --installed \
     --qf '%{n} | %{yumdb_info.reason} | %{yumdb_info.installed_by}' --all \
    | awk -F'|' ' $2 ~ /user/ && ($3 != 4294967295) { print $1 }'  \
    | sort -u > pkgs_a.lst
```

The second awk condition is used to exclude packages that were installed by the installer. The installer's user-id was apparently stored as 4294967295 - alternatively you can write something like `($3 == 0 || $3 == your-user-id)`.

Note that this command works on Fedora up to release 21 - but e.g. not on release 23, because the command `repoquery` was replaced with `dnf repoquery`. And [`dnf repoquery`](http://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.org/en/latest/repoquery.html) does not understand the `%{yumdb_info.reason}` tag.

Comment: I'm not sure if this approach will get everything, I noticed these on my system when I ran `repoquery ...`: "Invalid yumdb querytag 'reason' for installed pkg: HandBrake-cli-0.9.5-1.fc14.x86_64"

Comment: @slm, hm, from what repository was handbrake installed? Perhaps the repository setup has something to do with it?

Comment: I think it might have been a standalone RPM that I installed using `yum localinstall ...`. I had a fair amount of packages that fell into that camp though.

Comment: `repoquery --installed --qf '%{n} - %{yumdb_info.reason}' --all 2>&1|grep -v "user$"|grep -v "dep$" |wc -l` returned 90 packages.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way, and it's worked for a long time is:

```
yum-debug-dump => gives file.

yum-debug-restore <file-from-debug-dump>
```

...which works much like the get/set selections dpkg command, AIUI. Also note that if you are replaying history you can use:

```
yum history addon-info last saved_tx => gives file
yum load-tx <file-from-addon-info>
```

...instead of having to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82888/1131) I've come up with following `yum history` based solution:

Get all detailed history on all yum install transactions (i.e. no upgrades), excluding those execited as part of initial installer actions (transactions 1 and 2 on my system, attributed to user 'System'):

```
$ yum history list all | awk -F'|' \
                            '$4 ~ /Install/ && $2 !~ /System/ {print $1}' \
    | xargs yum history info > yum_history
```

Filter explicitly installed packages and cut off version prefixes.

```
$ < yum_history grep '[^-]\<Install\>' | \
  awk '{ print $2 }' \
  | sed 's/\(-[0-9]\+:\|-[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\|-[0-9]\+-\|-[0-9]\+git\).\+\(\.fc1[1-7]\.\|\.noarch\).*$//' \
  | sort > hist_pkg_list
```

The ugly regular expression is needed such that all kinds of version suffixes are matched.

The results look quite fine on my system.

A comparison against the [repoquery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82882/1131) ansatz (on my system):

```
method         # packages
―――――――――――――――――――――――――
repoquery      569
repoquery-2nd  216
yum history    214
```

(I piped the repoquery results through sort -u)

Why are there differences? Because repoquery includes all the packages from transactions 1 and 2, i.e. all packages which were installed by the Fedora installer. This explains why repoquery includes the mentioned packages xorg-x11-
drv-mga and friends.

Comparing repoquery-2nd and yum-history shows that repoquery-2nd is more accurate - it does not include some already removed packages. In addition it includes a few (2 on my system) packages from 'yum update'-operations, it seems.

### Warning

The above history-based method only lists all explicitly installed packages over the complete lifetime of the system. It does not balance out those packages which were removed in a later transaction. Thus, this method needs some manual curating of the results and should only be used on systems were `repoquery` is not available.

Comment: Nice way to take the best of both our answers! I'd give you more than a +1 if I could for the eventual solution + the nice comparison of the various ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I have an older version of Fedora (14) so my yum includes a less feature rich version of `yum`, but you might want to take a look at the `yum history` feature. I believe you can get the info you're looking for from that command.

#### history list

```
$ sudo yum history list
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
ID     | Login user             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   862 | System <unset>         | 2013-07-12 18:00 | Install        |    1   
   861 | System <unset>         | 2013-07-09 03:11 | Install        |    1   
   860 | System <unset>         | 2013-07-01 13:40 | Install        |    1   
   859 | System <unset>         | 2013-06-29 22:07 | Install        |    1   
   858 | System <unset>         | 2013-06-25 22:33 | Install        |    1 P<
   857 | System <unset>         | 2013-06-23 22:28 | Update         |    1 >E
   856 | System <unset>         | 2013-06-23 21:33 | Install        |    1   
   ...
```

You can go back to the very first transaction by passing a list of numbers to `yum history list`:

```
$ sudo yum history list `seq 1 10`
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
ID     | Login user             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    10 | Sam M. (local) <saml>  | 2010-12-18 23:23 | Install        |    2   
     9 | Sam M. (local) <saml>  | 2010-12-18 23:15 | Install        |   38   
     8 | Sam M. (local) <saml>  | 2010-12-18 23:12 | Install        |    1   
     7 | Sam M. (local) <saml>  | 2010-12-18 23:09 | Install        |    1  <
     6 | Sam M. (local) <saml>  | 2010-12-18 22:37 | Install        |    1 > 
     5 | Sam M. (local) <saml>  | 2010-12-18 21:57 | Install        |    1   
     4 | System <unset>         | 2010-12-18 21:21 | Install        |    5   
     3 | System <unset>         | 2010-12-18 21:18 | Install        |    4   
     2 | System <unset>         | 2010-12-18 21:10 | Install        |    3   
     1 | System <unset>         | 2010-12-18 19:14 | Install        | 1189
```

#### history info

The following will show you what was installed as part of the 1st yum transaction:

```
$ sudo yum history info 1 | less
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
Transaction ID : 1
Begin time     : Sat Dec 18 19:14:05 2010
Begin rpmdb    : 0:da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
End time       :            19:42:43 2010 (1718 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 1189:8c21e9e377c3ebdee936916208f74232d5d6235f
User           : System <unset>
Return-Code    : Success
Transaction performed with:
Packages Altered:
    Dep-Install ConsoleKit-0.4.2-3.fc14.x86_64
    Dep-Install ConsoleKit-libs-0.4.2-3.fc14.x86_64
    Dep-Install ConsoleKit-x11-0.4.2-3.fc14.x86_64
    Dep-Install GConf2-2.31.91-1.fc14.x86_64
    Dep-Install GConf2-gtk-2.31.91-1.fc14.x86_64
    Dep-Install ModemManager-0.4-4.git20100720.fc14.x86_64
    Install     NetworkManager-1:0.8.1-10.git20100831.fc14.x86_64
    Dep-Install NetworkManager-glib-1:0.8.1-10.git20100831.fc14.x86_64
    Install     NetworkManager-gnome-1:0.8.1-10.git20100831.fc14.x86_64
    Install     NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.1-1.fc14.x86_64
```

Notice how yum reports whether a package was explicitly installed or installed because it was needed by a dependency. You could parse this info and get your list of packages that were explicitly installed.

Comment: I've added an answer based on your `yum history` idea, it also compares the results against the `repoquery` based method. As a side-effect I've extended my repoquery answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
dnf repoquery --qf "%{name}" --userinstalled > userinstalled.txt
```

Comment: As you look over the other 5 answers here, what do you notice that is different about your answer?  There is absolutely no explanation of *why* or *how* your answer is better of different.  It would be good if you could provide some description of you answer that covers these things.

Comment: @StephenRauch, this command isn't included in the other answers, because it's a recent dnf addition. The `--userinstalled` switch was just [added to dnf in May](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/pull/797). I've tested it, and it gives accurate results. Modulo the kernel/kernel-core/kernel-modules packages which aren't really user-installed. It also also contains all `*-debuginfo` packages - but they can be easily filtered out, if necessary.

Comment: @maxschlepzig, thanks for the feedback, but this was actually a bit of a rhetorical question, trying to educate/prompt the answer-er into explaining that in the answer.

Comment: @StephenRauch, fair enough, some editing certainly would be appropriate and would allow me to mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To list packages *you* have installed, try this *one-liner*:

```
alias yum-userinstall="yumdb search command_line install* | grep command_line\ = | sort | uniq | sed -r -e 's/command_line = (.*)/yum \1/g'"
```

Result:

```
# yum-userinstall
     yum install bind-utils
     yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
     yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
     yum install lsof
     yum install nano
     yum install nfs-utils libnfsidmap
     yum install nmap-ncat
     yum install openscap-scanner
     yum install open-vm-tools
```

PS1: it doesn't show dependencies

PS2: it is sorted alphabetically

PS3: it doesn't show if you have removed the package later

Answer (score -1):

What I did (forgot the details, and I'm a lazy bum, so...

Get all installed packages: `rpm -qa > file`

Use `sed(1)` to get rid of version numbers and such (keep the architecture, if required). This required a few iterations to get it right, you want to replace the last stretch of `-[0-9.]-[0-9].fc23` or similar by nothing, but there are funny version "numbers" too.

After installing as normal, do a `yum -y install $(< file)` (or `dnf`, as required).

You'll get some fallout of packages that don't exist anymore, or changed name, or were replaced by others.

Comment: Ok, but this will mark all previously installed packages as user-intalled on the destination host. Even if they originally were only installed as a dependency.