# How do i get installer user-id?

Tags: fedora, yum

I have a project whereby i have to extract configurations from one linux pc and emulate it on another.

I am focusing on extracting the packages installed during the installation of the fedora. This link: [Fedora replicate package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82882) helped me to extract the packages installed by the installer during the initial setup. However i have no idea how to get the installers user-id so that i can sort the packages installed initially and packages installed later on by the admin

1 ) How can i get the installers user-id?

2 ) Is there any open source software which can help to extract cofiguration from one linux pc and emulate on another?

Comment: I flagged your other question.  Both this question and the one I flagged would be better served by joining both questions together in this question.

Answer (score 0):

The installer runs as root. It doesn't have a special user id. Fortunately, you don't need it -- this doesn't have anything to do with what you want.

What you *do* want to do is look in `/root` on your installed system, for the file `/root/anaconda-ks.cfg`. The `%packages` section in this file will tell you what *package groups* are installed; but even better, if you take this kickstart file and feed it to the installer, *it will replicate your initial install* -- which sounds like just what you need. See the [Fedora documentation on kickstart](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/Installation_Guide/chap-kickstart-installations.html) for more.

If you do want to piece this together from the yum history, the date and time seems like a sufficient way to tell -- after all, the install is the first set of packages installed all in a row, and presumably there's some gap before the any after-the-fact admin-installed packages.