# Sync two installs of Fedora

Tags: fedora, yum, synchronization, dnf

I have a working PC and home PC - both run Fedora 24, in some cases I install packages on my work or home pc and forget to repeat the same install on my other working machine,

how do I bring dnf packages synced between 2 Fedora's? 
For example in pip/python I can do pip freeze > out.text and then install it  in a different virtualenv, does something like this exist in Fedora/Linux world?

thanks,
Dmitry

Comment: Doing clone using clonezilla or checking all installed packages and repeated on another working machine

Comment: Related answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82880/how-to-replicate-installed-package-selection-from-one-fedora-instance-to-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all the installed packages using `rpm`:

```
rpm -qa > list.txt
```

Installing packages can be [worked around](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/77770/is-it-possible-to-get-dnf-to-install-packages-listed-in-a-text-file/) like this:

```
dnf install $(cat list.txt)
```

(unless you hit the limit of command-line arguments)