# Syncronize installed and uninstalled packages between fedora installations

Tags: fedora, rpm, dnf

I am planning on basically cloning a fedora installation between two different machines. I am doing clean installation in the new system.
However, I would like to know if it is possible to not only copy over the already installed packages, which I know is easily possible.
See [Sync two installs of Fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332514/sync-two-installs-of-fedora) or [How to replicate installed package selection from one Fedora instance to another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82880/how-to-replicate-installed-package-selection-from-one-fedora-instance-to-another)

My question then would be if it is possible to not only install all missing packages, but also remove those, which are not installed on the source system? I found something like this is possible with apt, using `apt-clone`, but I found nothing in the rpm/dnf environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same method, really. Get your local list of packages, get the remote list, use `sort` to sort them, use `comm -2 -3 local.txt other.txt` to get the entries that are only in your local installation. Then first uninstall these, and afterwards install the remote list. (If you're using `dnf shell`, you can combine these steps into one.)

Note that this 100% sounds as if you need a good backup solution for your files and settings, as installing a fresh fedora would not unlikely to be faster.

Comment: Thanks, I do back up all my personal data and the necessary stuff in /. But then it needs to be done manually, in another program, and there' s no integrated way of doing that.